# Printing matrix in stacked cell with print.char.matrix() function in R

Tags: r

This the matrix result from my regressions models:

```
linear_models=structure(c(-0.9051, 2.0445, 0.0075, 0, -3.9959, 7.4458, 0, 0, 
-0.0666, 0.4933, 0.8627, 0.4268), .Dim = c(2L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("(Intercept)", "complete.ini$idiff_3m.grb[-c(502:504)]"
    ), c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)", "Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)", "Estimate", 
    "Pr(>|t|)")))
```

I use this command below to return names for each 2 columns. I have 3 names , so I have 6 models:

```
names(dimnames(linear_models)) <- c("         Variables",
                                    "     (Model 1)     (Model 2)      (Model 3)")
```

Now, I use the `print.char.matrix()` function from `Hmisc` package to do the following:

```
print.char.matrix(round(linear_models,4), col.txt.align = "left", col.names = TRUE,row.names = TRUE)

+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|                   Variables          |Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|(Intercept)                           |   -0.9051|   0.0075   |-3.9959|0|-0.0666|0.8627|
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|complete.ini$idiff_3m.grb[-c(502:504)]|   2.0445 |   0        |7.4458 |0|0.4933 |0.4268|
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

It is not well adjusted. And the names of the models are erased.

The output that I need is this one:

```
+------------------------------------------+----First Model--+---Second Model--+---Third Model---+
    |                   Variables          |Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|
    +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |(Intercept)                           |-0.9051 | 0.0075 |-3.9959 |    0   |-0.0666 |0.8627  |
    +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |complete.ini$idiff_3m.grb[-c(502:504)]| 2.0445 |   0    |7.4458  |    0   |0.4933  |0.4268  |
    +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

There is other functions/packages that delivery the same idea I want, with stacked cells printed?

Comment: Did you try `stargazer()`?

Comment: @ANG I dont want to use in LATEX.

Comment: You can get a text output with `stargazer()`. You just have to specify `type = "text"`. [Here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stargazer/versions/5.2.2/topics/stargazer) is a good starting point